# Text after compile "setPort(self, int): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'"

Tags: python

Hello i making webbrowser and i have problem with set a proxy port with textbox.

> setPort(self, int): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'

setHostName  working perfectly but this setPort not...

```
def on_click_button_reloadproxy(self):

        textboxproxyipValue = self.textboxproxyip.text()
        textboxproxyportValue = self.textboxproxyport.text()

        proxy = QtNetwork.QNetworkProxy()
        proxy.setType(QtNetwork.QNetworkProxy.HttpProxy)
        QtNetwork.QNetworkProxy.setApplicationProxy(proxy)

        proxy.setHostName(textboxproxyipValue)
        proxy.setPort(textboxproxyportValue)
```

Comment: Why are you passing in a string when `setPort()` requires an `int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you what the problem is. The `setPort` method expects an integer. You're passing it the value of a textbox, which is going to be a string. Hence the `unexpected type 'str'` error message.

You need to convert the textbox value to an integer before passing it to `setPort`.

```
proxy.setPort(int(textboxproxyportValue))
```